# What does $ A - \langle A \rangle $ mean?

Tags: textbook-and-exercises, mathematics, linear-algebra

I've seen the uncertainty of $A$ written as $$ (\Delta A)^2 = \langle (A - \langle A \rangle)^2 \rangle. $$ But what does this even mean since $ A $ is an operator and $ \langle A \rangle $ is a scalar. How can we compute the difference of the two?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For any vector $v$ and scalar $\alpha$, we have $\alpha v = \alpha I v$, so multiplication by a scalar $\alpha$ behaves the same way as the linear operator $\alpha I$. Therefore, we interpret $A - \langle A \rangle$ as $A - \langle A \rangle I$.

Answer (score 4):

Note that

$$\big(Z - \langle Z \rangle \big)^2 = Z^2 - 2Z \langle Z \rangle + \langle Z \rangle^2  $$

And therefore
$$ \langle \big(Z - \langle Z \rangle \big)^2  \rangle = \langle Z^2 - 2Z \langle Z \rangle + \langle Z \rangle^2 \rangle  $$

Then by linearity, we have

\begin{align}  \langle Z^2 - 2Z \langle Z \rangle + \langle Z \rangle^2 \rangle  &= \langle Z^2 \rangle - \langle 2Z \langle Z \rangle \rangle + \langle \langle Z \rangle^2 \rangle \\
&= \langle Z^2 \rangle - (2\langle Z \rangle) \langle Z \rangle + \langle Z \rangle^2 \\
&= \langle Z^2 \rangle -  2 \langle Z \rangle^2  + \langle Z\rangle^2 \\
&=  \langle Z^2 \rangle -  \langle Z \rangle^2 
\end{align}

So therefore,

$$ (\Delta Z)^2 = \big(Z - \langle Z \rangle \big)^2 = \langle Z^2 \rangle -  \langle Z \rangle^2 $$

Which is what you see if you search up [Variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Definition)